# rs232 communication creates error frequently

Tags: c++, c, serial-port

I know this question is not new and it's possible to google for some example codes/class to do rs232 communication.
However, now I'm already using a class. But it works sometimes but very often don't. The communication just stops
It will take me a great deal of time to read all serial communication concepts and debug this code

Could I have some help from SO?

Thanks,

PS: by the way, in my project, I need to frequently send a string (array of char) to another rs232 terminal continuously or at some defined instances. 
Can the error be caused by not closing, reopening RS232/COM handle along with each time of communication?

Please, I've included my code

[RS232.cpp](http://pastebin.com/dessEMBL)
[RS232.hpp](http://pastebin.com/fW2WpQmm)
[RS232_client](http://pastebin.com/D03sAitG)

Edit01:

RS232_client is the code written on the other side. My side is a PC using win7, project is compiled with MSVS2008

About the error in my code, it's sometimes when I call "int RS232::Write(double* joints)", it raises the error and the transmission stops, showing nothing on PC's side

Edit02:

As @Chris Stratton suggests, my problem might be from bad written rs232 class without necessary checking. So I tested my project with another class downloaded from CodeProject CSerial. I put the code here for reference

[Serial.cpp](http://pastebin.com/E4C35D9b)
[Serial.h](http://pastebin.com/Wgf9g7bh)

And this is how I adapt this class to my code:

[my adaptation](http://pastebin.com/DhRzQV7Y)

So, the process from PC side is the same, i.e., send a string, wait to read 's' or 'S', and send a "q\r" for quitting.

for the 3 steps above with this new code, I can do step 1 OK, but for step 2, it hangs there as if no (reading) event is evoked

```
        // Wait for an event
        lLastError = serialPort.WaitEvent();   // it waits here forever!!!!
        if (lLastError != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            ShowError(serialPort.GetLastError(), _T("Unable to wait for a COM-port event."));
```

Comment: since I don't have much concept in the work. I cannot define what's really the problem

Comment: FYI using `GetCommState` is almost always wrong.  You don't want to inherit settings from the last program to use the port, you want to change them all.  The only thing `GetCommState` is good for is inspecting the configuration for troubleshooting purposes, not during connection.

Comment: I tested both cases, close and reopen port at every communication (which is similar to what you said - GetCommState during communication), and only open once and both fails

Comment: There is no reason to close and reopen the serial port each time you want to communicate. And, closing the port can lose received data. Keep it open.

Comment: @SonLe: Actually, what I said is "don't use GetCommState, fill in every entry of the DCB structure yourself"

Comment: I can't really help any more without knowing what error you're getting.

Comment: I actually send/read to/from a device through RS232. The usage was described previously. The communication goes like OK for some transmissions, sometimes it raises an sudden error and further transmission is stopped. In RS232::Write, I put the format of sending string and read/write sequence that I use.

Comment: You should be checking the return value of ReadFile() and not just the buffer which it will only touch if it is successful in reading something.

Comment: I'll be checking it. It'll take a while for me though

Comment: 1. Show us your code where the issue is. 2. Tell us what compiler you are using. 3. Tell us what platform you are using; RS232 is on many embedded systems too. 4. Tell us your errors.  5. Edit your post with these answers.

Comment: I communicate from PC to a device. When there's transmission error. The device stops. On PC's side, I can't see error showed up. Partly, it's because my current RS232 code is either poor to handle error feedback or the device's side does not release enough information

Comment: Are you sure device is OK? You need to use COM port sniffer, like PortMon.

Comment: Not sure whether a DWORD and an int are the same size. Try changing the int n, in your read/write routine to DWORD n and remove the cast.  Also it might be better to read more than one character at a time (say 32 or 64) and then search through your buffer for the S/s character.  You may be getting a buffer overrun because the code is too slow processing the write buffer.

Comment: thanks @Alex, @cup! I'll be checking and give feedback soon

Answer (score 0):

I finally can have an RS232 module that works freeing of the weird sudden stopping. Here I upload the new version of [RS232.cpp](http://pastebin.com/FYvAUsZS)

The only different between the two versions is in new RS232_open(), I do not use GetCommState. Instead, the configuration is set by BuildCommDCBA using a string of setting baudr

Thanks for the help of SO!